# An error with routes [ruby on rails]

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, scaffolding

I have generated a form called Clients by using scaffold , then when I decided to change its url form routes file , I typed this command

```
match '/book', to: 'clients#new'
```

and now the problem is : I having two links for the new action , the first link is localhost:3000/clients/new , and the second one is localhost:3000/book , how to delete the first one ( clients/new ) , and thats also what I want to do for update / delete / index actions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in routes.rb file:

```
resources :clients, except: :new
```

Comment: Does is it going to affect on my nested resources ? , because i have  `resources :clients do resources :city .... end`

Comment: No, it won't affect it. Use syntax: `resources :clients, except: :new do resources :city ... end` or even instead of `except` you can use `only`. I saw you want to use it only for `index` and `show` action, so use `resources :clients, only: [:show, :index] do ... end`